# Как правильно печатать на термальном (чековом) принтере

Tags: c#

Имею принтер Epson TM-T58. Печатаю на ESC/POS. Поставил дровишки с сайта производителя. Попробовал распечатать как через обычный принтак - кракозябры, кодировка или шрифт не нравится, это и так понятно. Может кто подкинуть готовый примерчик на C# который бы смог подключиться к COM1 и отправить команды для печати, к примеру, слова - "Привет"? Осилил на яве это дело, а вот на C# так и не смог. Мне достаточно наброска даже для другой модели. Какую библиотеку использовать в принципе тоже не важно.

Comment: [Класс SerialPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: SerialPort serialPort;
serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");
serialPort.Open();

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: "Доступ к порту 'COM1' закрыт." - собственно, затык начинается отсюда)

Comment: Решение в лоб: если запускаешь по F5 из студии - то запустить студию под администратором, если просто файл запускаешь - то так же запускать под администратором

Comment: знаю, но увы, не помогает режим админа. Может как-то штатный драйвер не дает работать?

Comment: вторая причина такой ошибки: этот порт уже кем-то занят/открыт

Comment: пожалуй все-таки да, он был занят, занят штатными дровами EPSON, снес их - и все заработало

Comment: @Wayer если у принтера были штатные дрова - у него, скорее всего, есть более высокоуровневый интерфейс нежели COM. Документации-то к дровам нет?

Comment: Я уже все сделал) Нет, документации не было, я просто наобум удалил все драйвера которые ставил с сайта производителя, и стал на COM1 слать запросы, и все норм. Выставил Encoding 866, пару команд ESC/POS и вуаля, текст пошел печататься.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Собственно, спустя некоторое кол-во времени, я таки разобрался, как отсылать команды. Оставлю тут небольшой пример:

```
SerialPort serialPort;
serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");
serialPort.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("CP866");
serialPort.Open();

const string ESC = "\u001B"; ///ESC command (1B)
const string Init = ESC + "\u0040"; ///Init printer commands - ESC @ (1B 40)
const string CommandSize = ESC + "\u0021"; ///Set size chars - ESC ! (1B 21)
const string CommandDoubleSize = CommandSize + "\u0030"; ///Double charsize - ESC ! 0 (1B 21 30)
const string CommandDefaultSize = CommandSize + "\u0000"; ///Default style - ESC ! null (1B 21 00)


if(serialPort.IsOpen) {
    serialPort.Write(Init);
    serialPort.Write("Привет!");
    serialPort.Write(CommandDoubleSize + "Привет!" + CommandDefaultSize);
}

serialPort.Close();
```

К принтаку обычно документация идет, какие команды принтер кушает, а для тех кто в танке, отправляем просто HEX вариант этой команды, в примере показал, как изменить шрифт на моем принтере, в частности, сделать его большим.

А у тех, у кого ошибка из серии "Доступ к порту 'COM1' закрыт." - удалите весь софт от принтера, даже дрова, пусть вообще не будет определен в системе.

Answer (score 2):

Я такое сделал с помощью записи RTF и даже при помощи Google Chrome'а. Вот пример напрямую из [репозитория](https://github.com/Acolyte/Payment-Terminal-Web), код RichTextBoxPrintctrl доступен там же:

```
PrintDocument Document = new PrintDocument();
RichTextBoxPrintCtrl Control = new RichTextBoxPrintCtrl();
try
{
    Control.LoadFile(FinalReceiptFilename);
    Document.PrintPage += _printDocument_PrintPage;

    Document.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "VPK 80";
    Document.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;
    Document.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = Document.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 0;
    Document.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 10;
    Document.PrinterSettings.MaximumPage = 1;
    Document.PrinterSettings.MinimumPage = 1;
    foreach (System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize PaperSize in Document.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes)
    {
        if (PaperSize.PaperName == ReceiptSize)
        {
            Document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = PaperSize;
            break;
        }
    }

    Document.Print();

    return true;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Terminal.Log4NET.Error("Ошибка печати чека: " + e.Message + ", детали: " + e.StackTrace);
}
```

Для печати также можно использовать Google Chrome - там лучше всего получается использовать стили для Print View и печать через обычный механизм этого браузера. Для этого был создан файл print.css и подключался на странице где будут печататься чеки - стили в нем были исключительно для чека в скрывали все остальное.

Comment: вы не поняли, мне нужно было подключиться к локальному com-порту, и отправить набор байт-комманд печати, с последующей печатью текста

Comment: А какая разница? Операционная система подключается тоже через COM порт, единственная разница здесь что вы используете более низкоуровневое решение, чем мое. В моем случае у вас лучший контроль над форматом текста, символами и другими вещами. Добавив принтер в Принтерах и Факсах (указав COM порт и другие параметры), вы сможете печатать через ESCPOS.

Comment: У меня, в первую очередь, не принтер для печати страничек, а POS-оборудование. Штатная система POS-команд не всегда подходит, так как производитель сам решает, какие команды использовать для той или иной операции. Текст печатать можно, а вот встроенные функции с печатью документа Вы, увы, использовать не сможете. Поэтому я и искал вариант подключения к порту и отсылке нужных мне байтов для изменения шрифтов, позиций, стилей текста. Ваш вариант, увы, выдал мне кракозябры, специально решил потестить.

Comment: Хм, я работал с Custom VPK 80II, он использовался как POS принтер для печати чеков в платежном терминале. Также, как уже я упоминал, большинство POS принтеров поддерживает ESCPOS. Вероятно у вашего принтера была реализация, отличная от этого, поэтому вам пришлось использовать отсылку команд напрямую. У меня тоже сначала печатались крякозябры, но это было потому что я не установил шрифты (уже не помню где и как) для принтера.